# Can't sign up for G Suite personal, not able to contact support

Tags: google-workspace-for-business

I signed up for **G Suite personal** in order to have a custom domain name. Later, I decided to let my account get deleted and contacted Google support for assistance. At a later point, I decided to use G Suite personal, so I *tried* to sign up again.

**1.** First, I filled out this form. Supposedly, this is G Suite *personal*, but it doesn't seem like it. I found the link [here](https://support.google.com/a/answer/53926?hl=en). It says that it's used by a personal account and it is true. This is the @gmail.com address and the custom domain I used previously.

[image: 1]

**2.** By clicking "why", I was redirected to a page that suggests an URL which just displays this message when logging in.

[image: 2]

I got redirected from one help-landingpage to another until I had an entire row of browser tabs open, so I decided to contact Google support. They are very friendly and would certainly help me. Unfortunately, an access PIN is required.

So the voice on the phone stated two URL's:

- work.google.com/pin
- work.google.com/access

[image: 3]

Both of them require a G Suite account, which I'm unable to set up. If someone points me to a way to contact Google support, it would be sufficient for an answer, because this would solve my problem *(and I would share the solution afterwards, of course)*. Otherwise, is there any reason why I can't sign up and get even contact support without an account? I'm struggeling to get someone from Google on the phone.

Comment: If you figure out how to get meaningful support from Google regarding G Suite, please be sure to post it here. I'm not encountering the problem you've described, but it's bizarre that it's so difficult to contact a real person (or useful help pages, for that matter) to get started with G Suite. It's as though they're trying to deter new users.

Comment: I didn't feel deterred right from the beginning. But after deleting the account, re-creation obviously seems like an unexpected use case. And I'm guessing if Google had a "general support" phone number, end users would keep calling there endlessly for blatant support on almost anything. So that's why it's so hard, if not impossible to reach someone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since mail@[...] was taken and inaccessible to me, I just registered mail2@[...] at first.

Then I had access to the admin console, I could call Google support and that's when I managed to get mail@[...] back and remove the temporarily created other address.

This is a bit of a workaround, but most importantly: I was able to call Google support. I didn't need to, because from this point, all I had to do is:

- Add the original mail@[...] account to the super administrator group
- Remove the old one